# How to implement a master machine controlling several slave machines via Linux C++

Tags: c++, sockets, cloud, mapreduce

could anyone give some advice for how to implement a master machine controlling some slave machines via C++?

I am trying to implement a simple program that can distribute tasks from master to slaves. It is easy to implement one master + one slave machine. However, when there are more than one slave machine, I don't know how to design.

If the solution can be used for both Linux and Windows, it would be much better.

Comment: Are you sure you want to roll your own for such a task?  Have you looked into Beowulf?

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure. Because My current project is using GPUs and Hadoop seems to be too complicated for the project, I just implement a  simple program which can assign tasks to slaves and monitor the progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use should a framework rather than make your own. What you need to search for is *Cluster Computing*. one that might work easily is [**Boost.MPI**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/mpi.html)

Answer (score 0):

We need to know more, but basically you just need to make sure the slaves don't block each other.  Details of doing that in C++ will get involved, but the first thing to do is ask yourself what the algorithm is.  The simplest case is going to be if you don't care about waiting for the slaves, in which case you have

```
while still tasks to do
   launch a task on a slave
```

If you have to have just one job running on a slave then you'll need something like an array of flags, one per slave

```
 slaves : array 0 to (number of slaves - 1)
 initialize slaves to all FALSE

 while not done
    find the first FALSE slave -- it's not in use
    set that slave to TRUE
    launch a job on that slave

    check for slaves that are done
    set that slave to FALSE
```

Now, if you have multiple threads, you can make that into two threads

```
 while not done
    find the first FALSE slave -- it's not in use
    set that slave to TRUE
    launch a job on that slave

 while not done
    check for slaves that are done
    set that slave to FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie. I can get a better idea now. But I need to monitor the progress for each slave, which may block other slaves.  I just need to distribute tasks to different machines and monitor their progress.

Answer (score 0):

With n-machines, you need to keep track of which ones are free, and if there are none, load across your slaves (i.e. how many tasks have been queued up at each) and then queue on the lowest loaded machine (or whichever your algorithm deems best), say better hardware means that some slaves perform better than others etc. I'd start with a simple distribution algorithm, and then tweak once it's working...

More interesting problems will arise in exceptional circumstances (i.e. slaves dying, and various such issues.)

I would use an existing messaging bus to make your life easier (rather than re-inventing), the real intelligence is in the distribution algorithm and management of failed nodes.